# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while using GSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have this line of code

```
val event = Gson().fromJson(socketResponse.toString(), com.spaxiappuser.service.booking.event.Event::class.java)
```

Which throws the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.widget.TextView
>   declares multiple JSON fields named mMinWidth

My data class is as follows

data class Event(
        val tripParams: TripParams? = null,
        val onDemand: OnDemand? = null,

```
    @SerializedName("request_id")
    val requestId: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("driver_userid")
    val driverId: String? = null,

    val due: Due? = null,

    val standard: Standard? = null,

    val isToAllowBackPress: Boolean = false
```

Can anyone please let me know why this is happening?

Here is my stack trace :

```
 W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.widget.TextView declares multiple JSON fields named mMinWidth
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:926)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
 W/System.err:     at com.spaxiappuser.service.socket.EventManager.handleEvent(EventManager.kt:35)
 W/System.err:     at com.spaxiappuser.service.socket.Listener$listen$2.accept(Listener.kt:78)
 W/System.err:     at com.spaxiappuser.service.socket.Listener$listen$2.accept(Listener.kt:15)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:93)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:58)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66)
 W/System.err:     at com.spaxiappuser.service.socket.Listener$listen$1.subscribe(Listener.kt:50)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12197)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Any help in identifying the issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the classes your model references has a `TextView` somewhere in it (or extends TextView), and GSON is trying to interpret that as a class to be inflated from JSON.

Find it and either mark that field `transient`, or [otherwise exclude that field](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization).

Comment: Thanks! I added an @Transient before val/var and now it works!